# How to track events on rancher orchestration tool

Tags: docker, rancher

I am using rancher for managing my docker containers.Whenever containers on docker are deployed using rancher tool, the application that are there on that container gets deployed.I want to know where are the  changes that occur when docker containers hit the rancher tool are stored and how we can track them .

Answer (score 0):

The Admin -> Audit Log tab shows info about events that occur.  v1.2 will include additional info about containers being created/deleted by service reconciliation, such as when health checks fail.